# Section number flushed left but section body centred

Tags: sectioning, alignment

In my document (thesis) I would like to have the section-number always on the left handside, while the actual section-name should be centred. In pseudocode it would be something like this:
`\sectionnumber \hfill \sectionname \hfill`
I have tried using the package `titlesec` but without success. I will be most thankful for any advice on how to do this. Thank you for your time!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do as follows. The `\parbox[t]{0.8\columnwidth}` is in order to avoid that the title overlaps the number, which is typeset in a zero width box, so it doesn't influence the centering of the title.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
 {\Large\bfseries}% or whatever font you like
 {}%
 {0pt}
 {\makecenteredsectiontitle{\thesection}}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
 {\Large\bfseries}% or whatever font you like
 {}%
 {0pt}
 {\makecenteredsectiontitle{}}

\newcommand{\makecenteredsectiontitle}[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{#1}%
  \makebox[\columnwidth]{\parbox[t]{0.8\columnwidth}{\centering #2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\section{Short section title}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\section{Long section title that must be wrapped across lines, just to make a silly example}

\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is precisely what I needed! I'm much obliged :)